# su Admin on Mac OS X does not work as expected

Tags: bash, su

I'm tring to install PostgreSQL on Mac OS 10.6.4 and I need to authenticate as an administrator.  In the command line, I have:

> su Admin
>   Password:
>   shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied

My user is a standard (non-administrator) account, Admin is an administrator account, and the directory I'm working in when I execute 'su' is in my Downloads folder.  If I do 'su - Admin' then it works, but then I can't access the necessary files!  However, 'su Admin' should work because it leaves the environment unchanged.

How should I do this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Enable root](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090909081659323). Then:

```
su root
```

Comment: Results in "su: Sorry"

Comment: @jfm429, You might have to enable root first. I updated my answer with a link for Snow Leopard. What version of OSX are you using?

Comment: I really don't want to have to enable root.  This is an entirely different topic, but I need to be able to use PostgreSQL for an application but not force users to jump through hoops to use it.  I'm probably going to use SQLite for the local database and then have the option of syncing with PostgreSQL...

Comment: @jfm429, you could use root to install the DB and set-up permissions properly, then disable root.

Comment: That defeats the point; again, this needs to be an end-user-accessible process.  So far that's the problem I've seen with PostgreSQL is that it's simply insanely difficult to install.  The only installer package requires editing kernel settings, which applications should never need to change.

Comment: I've never hand any problems installing PostgreSQL. Any user should be able to install it in his home/ without any problems and without an Administrator or root account.

Comment: Do you have a list of the commands required to do that, including the setup?  I tried but ended up getting a bunch of errors; I can't remember which ones.

Comment: @jfm429, I believe ./configure && make worked for me. I think there are binary distributions for osx that should work too. If you're getting errors, you could post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Admin user have at least read and list (execute) access to your Downloads directory and home directory? Bear in mind that on Mac OS X, administrator accounts are *not* the root user (which [is disabled by default](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528)) and thus are constrained by file permissions like other mere mortals.

Administrator accounts *are*, however, sudoers, which allows them to assume many of the powers of root, but this has to be explicitly requested on a case by case basis - usually with `sudo`. If your `su Admin` shell is still running after the error message, try doing `sudo ls` - it should work as it will be run as if by root. Plain `ls` won't if Admin doesn't have access to that directory.

The answer is to give Admin access to any directories in your home folder you want it to be able to access. Either do this in the Finder with Get Info, or use `chmod`.

Comment: I did use 'sudo ls' and it worked.  However, I tried performing the installation using 'sudo' before every command and it still failed (couldn't find the current working directory for any of the scripts).  I ended up just doing it from the admin account.